# drawImage() implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have two canvases that are different sizes. My goal is copy the user's drawing from the main canvas to a second canvas as a scaled down version. So far the drawImage() and scale appear to be working, but the second canvas keeps the old version of the main drawing along with the new copy. I tried clearing it each time before calling drawImage(), but that doesn't appear to do anything. How can I copy just the current image to my secondary canvas each time the function runs?

```
$('#hand').dblclick(function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 //var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);
 var newCanvas = document.getElementById('scaledCanvas');
 var destCtx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
 destCtx.clearRect(0, 0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);
 destCtx.scale(.5,.5);
 destCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
});
```

I can include more code if necessary. I also just realized that scale keeps getting called; this explains why the new copied image would get smaller each time as well, so that might be another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple actually, you're using what's called a transform (translate, rotate, or scale).

In order to use them "freshly" each time you must save and restore the canvas state each time.

```
$('#hand').dblclick(function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 //var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);
 var newCanvas = document.getElementById('scaledCanvas');
 var destCtx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
 destCtx.clearRect(0, 0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);

 //save the current state of this canvas' drawing mode
 destCtx.save();

 destCtx.scale(.5,.5);
 destCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

 //restore destCtx to a 1,1 scale (and also 0,0 origin and 0 rotation)
 destCtx.restore();

});
```

It's also important to note you can push several times before calling restore, in order to perform many cool geometric tricks using recursive functions etc...

Take a look at this explanation of states and transformations: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Transformations

Hope this helps you understand canvas transforms a bit better.